# How allocate memory which is page size aligned?

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-management

I need to allocate memory which should be page size aligned. I need to pass this memory to an `ASM` code which calculates xor of all data blocks. I need to do this with `malloc()`.

Comment: *I need to do this with `malloc()`* Why have you already decided what the solution is?

Comment: [RTFM](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Aligned-Memory-Blocks.html)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are functions for this that you're supposed to use.

If you can't, for whatever reason, then the way this is generally done is by adding the block size to the allocation size, then using integer-math trickery to round the pointer.

Something like this:

```
/* Note that alignment must be a power of two. */
void * allocate_aligned(size_t size, size_t alignment)
{
  const size_t mask = alignment - 1;
  const uintptr_t mem = (uintptr_t) malloc(size + alignment);
  return (void *) ((mem + mask) & ~mask);
}
```

This has not been very deeply tested but you get the idea.

Note that it becomes impossible to figure out the proper pointer to `free()` the memory later. To fix that, we would have to add some additional machinery:

```
typedef struct {
  void *aligned;
} AlignedMemory;

AlignedMemory * allocate_aligned2(size_t size, size_t alignment)
{
  const size_t mask = alignment - 1;
  AlignedMemory *am = malloc(sizeof *am + size + alignment);
  am->aligned = (void *) ((((uintptr_t) (am + 1)) + mask) & ~mask);
  return am;
}
```

This wraps the pointer trickery a bit, and gives you a pointer you can `free()`, but you need to dereference into the `aligned` pointer to get the properly aligned pointer.

Comment: @glglgl: Do the same thing `malloc` does too. Write the original address in the 4 bytes preceding the address you give back to the user.

Comment: @AlterMann Hehe. Well, sure, since I need an integer and not a pointer. My usual restriction doesn't apply here, `void *` doesn't automatically convert to `uintptr_t`. :)

Answer (score 12):

I don't think is possible only with malloc. You can use [memalign()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memalign):

```
char *data = memalign(PAGESIZE, alloc_size);
```

Where `PAGESIZE` is the size of a page and `alloc_size` is the size of the memory that will be allocated.

The size of the page can be found with `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)`.

Answer (score 10):

Use [posix_memalign](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_memalign.3.html) to obtain memory already aligned.

Note: `valloc` & `memalign` both are obsoleted.

Answer (score 2):

Use [valloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/valloc) rather than `malloc` - it has the same signature as `malloc` but it allocates page-aligned memory. Note that you still free the memory subsequently using `free()`.

Note also that `valloc` is technically obsolete, so consider using [posix_memalign](http://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_memalign), although this is not such a simple replacement for `malloc` as it has a very different function signature.

Comment: `valloc` is documented to be *obsolete* so don't use it!

Comment: I suspect that `valloc` will be around for a long time yet. Note that it's not just a Linux-ism, as it's in BSD/Mac OS X/et al also. However I've added a note about using the rather more awkward `posix_memalign` just for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

// Linux-oriented,
// See my trickery to arrange yourself

I just wrote a program which has to allocate hardware-page-aligned memory ; here follows the *body* of the program containing the main() function :

The main() function calls an Func_a() function, which calls an Func_b() function which calls aforementioned Func_a() function, and so on ... ... recursively and without stop condition, thus indefinitely, burning the program stack, eventually causing SIGSEGV.

Should this help you :

```
#include "Func_A.h"
#include "Func_B.h"


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define STACK_SIZE (1024 * 1024)

int main(void)
{
  // Allocate a 2nd stack for the SIG_SEGV signal handler
  long pgsz = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
  printf("Page size is %ld\n", pgsz);

  long stacksize = STACK_SIZE;

  long sigstkpages = (STACK_SIZE + (pgsz - 1) ) / pgsz;

  void* newstack = calloc(sigstkpages, pgsz);
  if (NULL == newstack)
  {
    perror("calloc()\n");
    exit(2);
  }
  newstack = (void*) (((((long) newstack) + (pgsz - 1)) / pgsz) * pgsz);
  void* newstackhigh = (void*) (((long) newstack) + (stacksize - 1));
  stacksize = (newstackhigh - newstack) + 1;
  printf("Stack size is %ld\n", stacksize);

  printf("New Stack spans %p-%p  (%ld pages)\n", newstack, newstackhigh, sigstkpages);

  a();
}
```

And its output is :

Page size is 4096
Stack size is 1048576
New Stack spans 0x7f28435cd000-0x7f28436ccfff  (256 pages)
Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)

The coredump is expected here.