# How to allocate full memory pages

Tags: c++, c, linux, memory-management, x86-64

In C or C++, on Linux, I want to allocate heap memory in full pages of the system's memory page size.

(The purpose is that I want to increase the likelihood that harmful buffer overflows cause segmentation faults.)

When I allocate memory with C++ array new (`pointer = new char[size]`), where size is a multiple of `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)`, then still the (virtual) address the allocated memory will usually not be a multiple of `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)`, indicating that I've got a subset of a larger chunk, confirmed by the fact that writing to pointer[size] and a little bit beyond (forced buffer overflow) usually does not cause a segmentation fault.

My question here is, can I influence the memory allocation somehow to give me full memory pages.

The processor architecture I am interested in is x86_64 aka amd64. Operating system is either latest Ubuntu, or stable CentOS Linux (7.3), the latter comes with kernel 3.10 and gcc-4.8.

I do not care if the solution is in C or C++, therefore I ask to leave the C tag in this question.

Comment: just a thought, have a look at the source of electric fence

Comment: You mean [page-aligned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21550420/how-allocate-memory-which-is-page-size-aligned)?

Comment: @Arash yes, probably, if this gives full memory pages and not just allocates more and then fiddles with the start address. Reading man memalign now. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: There is a variety of memory allocation functions, but very few offer the kind of guarantee you want -- that the memory immediately immediately following the requested bytes is unallocated.  The system is free to allocate larger chunks if it wishes to do, even when you're requested size is a multiple of the page size.  It is also free to allocate memory from holes left behind by freeing previously-allocated memory.

Comment: @JohnBollinger If I cannot get a guarantee, I will be content with just increasing the likelihood.

Comment: @LudwigSchulze, as you wish, but I think making your code more obscure and complex is a poor tradeoff for merely changing the probability of a particular manifestation of UB.

Comment: Why not mmap guard pages (`PROT_NONE`) around your buffer?

Comment: mmap() would be useful http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html so memory debugging tools will use mmap to allocate pages.

Comment: @ pm100 a3f DilipKumar: electric fence uses mmap, which seems to support what I want. But on Linux, it seems to be even simpler: the mprotect man page contains a complete example program without mmap.

Comment: @LudwigSchulze thank you for info about mprotect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Just switching from `pointer = new char[size]` to `pointer = aligned_alloc(sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE), size)` resulted in proper page alignment and (so far, with small test programs) consistent generation of segmentation faults when exceeding the allocated range. As @JohnBollinger pointed out in his first comment to the question, the generation of segmentation faults is not guaranteed from the method of allocation alone. This can be fixed with 2):

2) The Linux man page for the function mprotect contains a complete example for restricting access to memory pages. The example also provides a signal handler for SIGSEGV, which I'm not interested in, default action (abort) is good enough for me. The example section from the man page follows. Note that applying mprotect to memory areas unrelated to mmap is a Linux-specific extension not covered by POSIX.

> EXAMPLE
>
> The  program  below  allocates four pages of memory, makes the third
>   of these pages read-only, and then  executes  a  loop  that  walks 
>   upward through the allocated region modifying bytes.
>
> An example of what we might see when running the program is the
>   following:
>
> ```
>        $ ./a.out
>        Start of region:        0x804c000
>        Got SIGSEGV at address: 0x804e000
> ```
>
> Program source
>
> ```
>    #include <unistd.h>
>    #include <signal.h>
>    #include <stdio.h>
>    #include <malloc.h>
>    #include <stdlib.h>
>    #include <errno.h>
>    #include <sys/mman.h>
>
>    #define handle_error(msg) \
>        do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)
>
>    static char *buffer;
>
>    static void
>    handler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *unused)
>    {
>        printf("Got SIGSEGV at address: 0x%lx\n",
>                (long) si->si_addr);
>        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
>    }
>
>    int
>    main(int argc, char *argv[])
>    {
>        char *p;
>        int pagesize;
>        struct sigaction sa;
>
>        sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
>        sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
>        sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
>        if (sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL) == -1)
>            handle_error("sigaction");
>
>        pagesize = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
>        if (pagesize == -1)
>            handle_error("sysconf");
>
>        /* Allocate a buffer aligned on a page boundary;
>           initial protection is PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE */
>
>        buffer = memalign(pagesize, 4 * pagesize);
>        if (buffer == NULL)
>            handle_error("memalign");
>
>        printf("Start of region:        0x%lx\n", (long) buffer);
>
>        if (mprotect(buffer + pagesize * 2, pagesize,
>                    PROT_READ) == -1)
>            handle_error("mprotect");
>
>        for (p = buffer ; ; )
>            *(p++) = 'a';
>
>        printf("Loop completed\n");     /* Should never happen */
>        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
>    }
> ```

Attribution of the preceding quote:

> This page is part of release 4.04 of the Linux  man-pages  project.
>   A description  of  the project, information about reporting bugs, and
>   the latest    version    of    this    page,    can     be     found  at http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/.